# Two beans with same name in different contexts

Tags: java, spring

I have the following beans in my contexs:

```
    <!-- Context 1 -->
<beans profile="ldap">
        <bean id="activeDirectoryAuthProvider" class="com.production.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
          <constructor-arg value="${ldap.login.provider.domain}"/>
          <constructor-arg value="${ldap.login.provider.url}" />
          <property name="useAuthenticationRequestCredentials" value="true" />
          <property name="convertSubErrorCodesToExceptions" value="true" />
        </bean>
</beans>

<!-- Context 2 -->

    <bean id="activeDirectoryAuthProvider" class="com.test.TestActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
      <constructor-arg value="${ldap.login.provider.domain}"/>
      <constructor-arg value="${ldap.login.provider.url}" />
      <property name="useAuthenticationRequestCredentials" value="true" />
      <property name="convertSubErrorCodesToExceptions" value="true" />
    </bean>
```

My goal is to use the first bean only for production version another one for test purposes.

Namely when I start test **based on production** context I expect that production bean would be replaced by test bean with needed configuration.

But unfortunately when I tried to create two beans with  same name only production bean is created and another one is ignored. Another thing that I noticed that when I tried to change test bean name to: **activeDirectoryAuthProvider1** then both beans are successfully created. Can anyone explain why it happen and suggest possible solution how it can be bypassed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use different contexts for development and production. In each context you define only the relevant bean (i.e. only 1 bean with a certain name). If you use maven you can put the test/development context under src/test/resources and the production context under src/main/resources

If you do not use maven there are other approaches. You can find an example here: http://mrhaki.blogspot.it/2009/02/use-spring-configurator-to-support.html

Comment: Yeah, we already use two different contexts, namely test context include production context. The initial idea was to use all production beans except a few beans like dataSource... to avoid to much duplication of beans around the project.

Comment: It should be possible to have 3 configuration files:
File 1: Production Beans Only
File 2: Development Beans Only
File 3: Shared Beans (Development and Production)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Spring Profiles you can have one for test and one for prod.

```
<beans profile="test">
     <!-- Context 1 -->

          <bean id="activeDirectoryAuthProvider" class="com.production.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
             <constructor-arg value="${ldap.login.provider.domain}"/>
             <constructor-arg value="${ldap.login.provider.url}" />
             <property name="useAuthenticationRequestCredentials" value="true" />
             <property name="convertSubErrorCodesToExceptions" value="true" />
          </bean>
</beans>

<beans profile="prod">
      <!-- Context 2 -->

       <bean id="activeDirectoryAuthProvider" class="com.test.TestActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
           <constructor-arg value="${ldap.login.provider.domain}"/>
           <constructor-arg value="${ldap.login.provider.url}" />
           <property name="useAuthenticationRequestCredentials" value="true" />
           <property name="convertSubErrorCodesToExceptions" value="true" />
       </bean>
</beans>
```

You can set the active profile in a various ways. Check the docs.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but unfortunately it is not option for us. I forgot to add to question that we already use spring profiling(Question already updated). Namely the initial idea was to have default and ldap profiles in order to switch between login strategies. Also we planed to specify @ActiveProfile("ldap") in integration tests to choose needed strategy.